# PHP SOAP version mismatch (wrong version)

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working on implementation of Royal Mail to our system. I would like to use their API, but I have no luck with it. I am still getting error:

```
[faultstring] => Wrong Version [faultcode] => VersionMismatch [faultcodens] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
```

I already tried SOAP version 1.2 but I am sure they use SOAP 1.1. Here is WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="TrackingAPIService" targetNamespace="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/track/V1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/track/V1" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<wsdl:documentation>Version 1.1.1</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/WSDLapi/track/V1" xmlns:tns="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/WSDLapi/track/V1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/track/V1" schemaLocation="Tracking_API_V1_1_1.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getSingleItemHistoryRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getSingleItemHistoryRequest" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getSingleItemHistoryResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getSingleItemHistoryResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getProofOfDeliveryRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getProofOfDeliveryRequest" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getProofOfDeliveryResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getProofOfDeliveryResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getMultiItemSummaryRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getMultiItemSummaryRequest" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getMultiItemSummaryResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getMultiItemSummaryResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getSingleItemSummaryRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getSingleItemSummaryRequest" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getSingleItemSummaryResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getSingleItemSummaryResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="faultResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:exceptionDetails" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="TrackingAPIServicePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="getSingleItemHistory">
        <wsdl:documentation>Provides a history of tracks for a single mail item.</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getSingleItemHistoryRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:getSingleItemHistoryRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getSingleItemHistoryResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getSingleItemHistoryResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="tns:faultResponse" name="faultResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getProofOfDelivery">
        <wsdl:documentation>Provides the details captured at the point of delivery as proof that delivery has occurred. Note that a proof of delivery is only captured by the delivery track for those service offerings that require a signature on delivery. Please also note that for data protection reasons the API does not currently supply the signature image captured at the point of delivery.</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getProofOfDeliveryRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:getProofOfDeliveryRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getProofOfDeliveryResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getProofOfDeliveryResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="tns:faultResponse" name="faultResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getMultiItemSummary">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getMultiItemSummaryRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:getMultiItemSummaryRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getMultiItemSummaryResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getMultiItemSummaryResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="tns:faultResponse" name="faultResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getSingleItemSummary">
        <wsdl:documentation>Provides the latest track for a mail item.</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getSingleItemSummaryRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:getSingleItemSummaryRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getSingleItemSummaryResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:getSingleItemSummaryResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="tns:faultResponse" name="faultResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="TrackingAPIServiceSoap11Binding" type="tns:TrackingAPIServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getSingleItemHistory">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getSingleItemHistory" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="faultResponse">
            <soap:fault name="faultResponse" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getProofOfDelivery">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getProofOfDelivery" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="faultResponse">
            <soap:fault name="faultResponse" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getMultiItemSummary">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getMultiItemSummary" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="faultResponse">
            <soap:fault name="faultResponse" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getSingleItemSummary">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getSingleItemSummary" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="faultResponse">
            <soap:fault name="faultResponse" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="TrackingAPIService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:TrackingAPIServiceSoap11Binding" name="TrackingAPIServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint">
        <soap:address location="https://api.royalmail.net/tracking"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
private static function generateIntegrationHeader($type){
    $version = '1.0';
    if ($type === 'Shipping') {
        $version = '2';
    } elseif ($type === 'Tracking') {
        $version = '1';
    }

    return [
        'identification' => [
            'applicationId' => self::APPLICATION_ID,
            'transactionId' => mt_rand(10000000, 100000000)
        ]
    ];
}

public static function status($trackingCode) {
    $mode = array (
        'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',  // use soap 1.1 client
        'trace' => true,
        'exceptions' => true
    );
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient(BASE_DIR.'/tridy/wsdl/ukroyal/Tracking_API_V1_1_1.wsdl', $mode);
        $client->__setLocation(self::ENDPOINT_URL_TRACK_PRODUCTION);
        $resp = $client->__soapCall('getSingleItemHistory', [self::generateSingleItemHistoryRequest($trackingCode)]);
        if($resp->trackdetail->header == "Delivered") {
            return ['status' => parcel::STATUS_DELIVERED];
        }
        return ['status' => parcel::STATUS_EN_ROUTE];
    }
    catch(SoapFault $ex) {
        //echo htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest());
        //echo htmlentities($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
        print_r($ex);
    }
}
```

Here is request I send:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1"
xmlns:ns2="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/track/V1">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:getSingleItemHistoryRequest>
        <ns2:integrationHeader>
            <ns1:identification>
                <ns1:applicationId>CENSORED</ns1:applicationId>
                <ns1:transactionId>20704393</ns1:transactionId>
            </ns1:identification>
        </ns2:integrationHeader>
        <ns2:trackingNumber>RQ221150275GB</ns2:trackingNumber>
    </ns2:getSingleItemHistoryRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

What can be wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem with a buyer of my OpenCart extension. Strange thing was that they are at the same version of OpenCart as multiple other users, including my demo site. After lots (and lots) of digging, I narrowed my problem down to a PHP bug that was fixed in 5.3.11.

Here's details of the bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49853

Basically, the stream_context part of the http header is being ignored, and that contains the client ID and secret.

Contained within is a workaround:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP-SOAP/' . PHP_VERSION . "\r\n" . $str_auth_header);
```

From this, I created the following fix:

```
if ((!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID')) || (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50311)) {
    ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP-SOAP/' . PHP_VERSION . "\r\n" .
        implode(
            "\r\n",
            array(
                'Accept: application/soap+xml',
                'X-IBM-Client-Id: ' . $this->client_id,
                'X-IBM-Client-Secret: ' . $this->client_secret,
            )
        )
    );
}
```

that I add before I set the `stream_context` option. This was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461916/6431922) on [PHP and Royal Mail Tracking API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311949/php-and-royal-mail-tracking-api).

Though it looks like you are not yet setting `stream_context` (as `$mode` only has `soap_version`, `trace` and  `exceptions`), but hopefully the PHP version bug explains the "VersionMismatch" / "Wrong Version" error.

Answer (score 0):

in my code I used old version like this :

```
$result = $this->serve()->__soapCall($functionName, $arguments);

protected function serve()

{

if (is_null($this->client))
{
    $this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, $this->options);
}
return $this->client;

}
```

then when I change to this, solve that :

```
$sms_client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

    $result =  $sms_client->$functionName($arguments);
```